# Refreshing List in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, refresh, sapui5

i want to refresh a list every 60 seconds

My code:

```
window.refreshProductsTimer = window.setInterval(function(){ 
                    var oModel = that.getView().getModel("Products");
                    oModel.refresh(true);               

                    var oView = that.getView();
                    oView.byId("productsList").setBindingContext("Products");
                }, 30000);
```

The Interval works but my list items doesn't refresh. Any ideas how can i refresh my view?

I've got a timer in my list like:

> 2day 15h 13m

It's calculated by a formatter function:

```
<List id="productsList"
        items="{ path: 'Products>/ProductDocumentSet' }">
        <items>
            <ObjectListItem title="{Products>Dono}" type="Active" press="onListItemPressed"
                icon="sap-icon://{path:'Products>AAucform',formatter: '.formatter.getIcon'}"
                >
                <firstStatus>
                    <ObjectStatus
                        text="{parts: [{path: 'Products>AAucendDate' },{path: 'Products>AAucendTime' }],
                        formatter: '.formatter.getCountdown'}"
                        state="{parts: [{path: 'Products>AAucendDate' },{path: 'Products>AAucendTime' }],
                        formatter: '.formatter.getCountdownStatus'}" />
                </firstStatus>
                <attributes>
                    <ObjectAttribute text="{parts: [{path: 'Products>ADldatesDate' },{path: 'Products>ADldatesTime' }],
                        formatter: '.formatter.getDateTimeShort'}" />
                    <ObjectAttribute text="{i18n>GlobalType}: {Products>AAucformDesc}" />

                </attributes>
            </ObjectListItem>
            </items>
    </List>
```

But the timer doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Get the ListBinding of your list and then call refresh:

```
var oList = oView.byId("productsList");
oList.getBinding("items").refresh(true);
```

Here is a working example that uses a sap.m.Table and loads its data every 5 seconds: https://jsbin.com/wujovujegi/edit?html,output

This one is with a list: https://jsbin.com/vadahiyufo/edit?html,output

The timestamp never changes. Is this the issue you have? Be aware that the proxy will block the requests after a short time because of "too many requests" (you can see this in the network traffic).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've edited my question perhapes you've got an idea

Comment: would you mind showing a little more code from your xmlview?

Comment: But it doesn't seems to work, too. It's exactly the same in my code. The interval works, the model is refreshing but the time doesn't change.

Comment: Right, it's the same issue. Now I'm a little confused. I'm not in the laptop anymore, I will have a look at this later. I guess the formatter is only called for the new entries, but I have to debug this later.